# Mix Count, Case and Distinct on a specific field

Tags: django

I have the following model:

```
class NoteLink(models.Model):
    note_source = models.ForeignKey(Note, related_name="links_sourced")
    note_target = models.ForeignKey(Note, related_name="links_targeting")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="links_created")
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I would like to count the amounts of links a note has that are public, so I have the following annotate:

```
Note.objects.annotate(public_links=Count(Case(
        When(links_sourced__is_public=True, then=1),
        output_field=IntegerField()))
)
```

The issue is that several users can create a link with the same source and target, and this counts links with the same source and target several time if the author is different. I would like to only count the links with a distinct note_source and note_target.

I know that `Count` has a `distinct=True` option. But how can I mix it with my `Case` to consider links not distinct if all but the author is same? Or in other words, how to only count the ones with a different note_target?

N.B: I am not using PostgreSQL but MySQL, so I cannot run distinct() on a specific field.

Edit: I am not interested into having the count in a separate variable or query. I need this value to be annotate to all my Notes.

Edit2: My goal is to annotate the values into a query that I will use further in my code. Not just to count the amount of distinct note. I already know different ways to do that. What I need is to annotate the Note.objects.all() with the field "public_links" and use the *same* query later in my code. A separate query containing the number of distinct public links would be non usable for me. The same goes for a query that wouldn't contain all my Notes.

Comment: You can used distinct(), but with values_list(). Like this :
values_list('name_field', flat=True).distinct()

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:-

```
from  django.db.models import Count
distinctNoteCount = Note.objects.filter(is_public=True).annotate(the_count=Count('note_source ',distinct = True))
```

You can distinct on note_source or note_target because I think it doesn't matter in your case you just want count should be of rows that contains distinct note_source and note_target.

Comment: But then I obtain a new query. I need the value to be annotate to my Note.objects so I can use it further in my code.

Comment: This will still give a me a new query where only the Notes with link_sourced__is_public=True will be gathered. I want to annotate all my notes, without filtering.

Comment: @RyanPergent, You only ask that should be public means is_public should be True. If you don't want to filter then try this `distinctNoteCount = Note.objects.values('note_source').annotate(the_count=Count('note_source ',distinct = True))
`.

Comment: I need a query that would contain all my Notes (model instances). Wouldn't this give me a dictionary of 'note_source'?

Comment: It's giving dictionary because I am using values, remove values it will give you instance. like this `distinctNoteCount = Note.objects.annotate(the_count=Count(‌​'note_source ',distinct = True))`